# Create Func<T, bool> from MemberExpression and Constant

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I don't do expression tree work enough to get this working...

Essentially what I want to create is `m.MyProperty == 1`, to be used in a method that takes `Func<T, bool>`.

I have a `MemberExpression` already. I've tried various things, but I just keep getting different errors.

I currently have something like this (that doesn't work):

```
object const = 1;
var equalExpression = Expression.Equal( memberExpression, Expression.Constant( const ) );
var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( equalExpression, Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ) ).Compile();
```

This gives me an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'm' of type 'MyType' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

I've tried re-working several different parts of this but haven't come up with anything that works.

The `const` is an object that can be any type, but should match the type of the `MemberExpression`.

**Solution:**

```
object c = 1;
var parameterExpression = (ParameterExpression)memberExpression.Expression;
var equalExpression = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(c));
var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExpression, parameterExpression).Compile();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this does not work is that you are using a "free-standing" parameter expression when compiling your lambda. You should create `Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ))` *before* making your `memberExpression`, and use the same *instance* of `ParameterExpression` both when you make a member expression and when you are compiling the lambda:

```
var pe = Expression.Parameter( typeof( T )); // <<== Here
var memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe /* Here */, "MyProperty");
var equalExpression = Expression.Equal( memberExpression, Expression.Constant( const ) );
var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( equalExpression, pe ).Compile();
//                                                                ^^
//                                                                ||
//                                                             And here
```

Comment: The `MemberExpression`is created from another method that takes in `( Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExression )` and that expression is turned into a `MemberExpression` and stored for use later. Is there a way to get the parameter out then?

Comment: @JoshClose I do not know of a reliable way to pull the parameter expression out of an expression based on it. You can always walk the expression tree using [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx), but the results that you get may be unreliable if multiple parameter expressions are used somewhere inside the inner expression.

Comment: @JoshClose Then you should modify that method.

Comment: I was able to get the `ParameterExpression` from doing `var pe = (ParameterExpression)memberExpression.Expression`. It works as you say now. Thanks!